# Why do I have to say “want you to do” instead of “want you do”?

Tags: grammar

I'm confused about 'want you to do (something)' and 'want you do (something)'.

Example:

> "I want you to eat fish" instead of "I want you eat fish" or "I want that you eat fish".

Can anyone explain what is the grammar rule for this?

Answer (score 6):

**SHORT ANSWER:**
The grammatical reason is that that is the rule with *want*.

**LONGER ANSWER:**
As discussed in somewhat more detail [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/3211/32), each English verb allows (the technical term is *licenses*) a limited set of possible forms in its complements. The only forms of clause which *want* licenses are those which employ a *marked infinitive*—that is, a verb in the infinitive preceded by the ‘particle’ *to*:

> <sup>ok</sup>I want you **to eat** fish.
>   <sup>ok</sup>I want **for** you **to eat** fish.

The construction with a gerund/participle is *sometimes* acceptable:

> <sup>?</sup> I want you **eating** fish when I return.

It is acceptable in this instance because the time adverbial *when I return* allows us to understand *eating* not as a gerund but as the participle in the marked infinitive progressive construction *to be eating*: you will be eating *at a particular time*. The *to be* in this construction has been conventionally deleted, in effect transforming *eating* into an adjective modifying *you*.

These are not acceptable:

> <sup>∗</sup> I want you **eat** fish. (*unmarked infinitive*)
>   <sup>∗</sup> I want **that** you **eat** fish. (*that* + *finite verb*)

Those are the rules with *want*. Each verb has its own rules, and you have to learn them one by one.

You will find more discussion of *licensing* [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/10334), [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/4425), and [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/9787)

---

<sup>∗</sup>  marks an utterance as unacceptable; <sup>?</sup>  marks an utterance as usually unacceptable.

Comment: I am doubtful about one of your example sentences - "I want for you to eat fish".

Comment: @Man_From_India About "I want for you to eat fish", check out this answer: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14795/3281.

Comment: I totally agree with you whatever you wrote there. And in my answer to this question below I have also mentioned that that "wish + for + " construction is possible, but they are not as common. Please see my answer below.

Comment: +1 a splendid answer. is it possible to have these many things in one brain ;) love you StoneyB again!

Comment: I think that "I want that you eat fish" is acceptable when talking about an unknown present circumstance. "I don't know what you generally eat on Fridays, but what I want is that you eat fish".

Comment: @Acccumulation Nope. "... but what I want is for you to eat fish".

Comment: @StoneyB That's expressing a desire regarding future states.

Answer (score 2):

**Usage of *WANT* (verb) - a few guidelines**

> We don’t use ***want*** with a that-clause:
>
> I **want you to** tidy your room before the visitors come.
>
> ***Not:*** I **want that** you tidy your room

From *Cambridge*

> New uses of the verb "**want**" are arriving all the time. Modern uses, some of them not yet registered in OED (Oxford English Dictionary)  and other dictionaries, are shown in the following examples -
>
> **(+ *that* - clause)** *You want that I should lose both my lieutenants together?* - A. Lejeune, 1986

From *The New Fowler's Modern English Usage*

> When **want** meaning **"desire"** is followed immediately by an infinitive
> construction, it does not take **for**:
>
> *I want you to go (**not:** want for you to go).*
>
> When **want** and the infinitive are separated by a word or
> phrase, however, **for** is used:
>
> *What I want is for you to go.*
>
> *I want very much for you to go.*
>
> **Want** in its meaning of "**have need, lack**"
> normally takes **for**: They'll not want for anything now that they've
> inherited his estate.

From *The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language*

Though *American Heritage Dictionary* opposes this usage yet sometimes this kind of usage is around the corner, though they are very rare (decision made by Google Ngram result)

> I want for you to eat fish. (Here "want" means "desire", and it's telling my desire)